# CSS float alignment uneven on wide screens

Tags: html, css, alignment

On wider screen resolutions the gap in-between widget areas 2&3 is obviously greater then the gap between widget area 1&2 making the 3 areas together look uneven.

```
.footer-widgets-1,
.footer-widgets-2,
.footer-widgets-3 {
    width: 332px;
}

.footer-widgets-1 {
margin-right: 36px;
}

.footer-widgets-1,
.footer-widgets-2 {
    float: left;
}

.footer-widgets-3 {
    float: right;
}
```

Is there a way to ensure even spacing between all 3 when using float: left on & a single float:right?

Comment: Using a grid system does that. Give each widget area a width percentage, or give a percentage margin left and right. Full screen width is 100% so margin, padding, border and element size contribute to that.

Comment: instead of `px`, use `%`.... if you give a fiddle, it'll be easier to provide a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="widget-group">

     <div class="footer-widgets-1">
     </div>
     <div class="footer-widgets-2">
     </div>
     <div class="footer-widgets-3">
     </div>

  </div>
.widget-group
{
     width: 1068px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: block;
     overflow: hidden;
}
.footer-widgets-1,
.footer-widgets-2,
.footer-widgets-3 {
    width: 332px;
    margin-right: 36px;
    float: left;
}

.footer-widgets-3 {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a "**Table**" display here. A Table display can be used in situations where you want to have control over the width of each column.

It is hard to give the exact solution you need, but something similar as below should be good to get you started.

1. Structure your widgets to enable them to be displayed as a table.

   ```
   <div id="tableContainer"> <!-- Serves as a container for the whole table -->
     <div id="tableRow"> <!-- We have only one row in this table, which has 3 columns, one for each widget. -->  
       <div class="footer-widgets-1"></div> <!-- First column. -->
       <div class="footer-widgets-2"></div> <!-- Second column. -->
       <div class="footer-widgets-3"></div> <!-- Third column. -->
     </div> <!-- End row. -->
   </div> <!-- End table. -->
   ```
2. Apply the styles to display your widgets as table cells within a table.

   ```
   #tableContainer {
     display: table;
   }

   #tableRow {
     display: table-row;
   }

   #footer-widgets-1, #footer-widgets-2, #footer-widgets-3 {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: top; /* Vertically aligns the content within each table cell at the top of the cell. */
     width: 33%; /* Set each table cell to approximately one-third of the total width of the page. */
   }

   /* Any other styles specific to each widget go here... */
   ```

Hope this works for you.